# Flash: moving a movieclip from a container to another while keeping same position and rotation

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, movieclip

As the title shows, I have 2 container MovieClips (mc1, mc2), each of them has a separate x,y, rotation. I want to take a child from mc1 and addChild() it to mc2 while keeping the same x, y, and rotation on the screen so you see the added child mc as if it didnt change position or rotation, just moved to the other MC. Any idea how?

Comment: `mc1` does maintain the same `rotation`, `x` and `y` values - it just renders differently as it will be positioned relative to the registration point of `mc1`.

Comment: thats the trick. I need some equation to change the x,y,rotation of the addedChild when it is added to mc2 to maintain the old position and rotation

Comment: As @MartyWallace pointed out, we need more info about the relative position of the containers in the stage hierarchy. Also, can you determine the rotation of one container relatively to the other or of each one of them relatively to the stage?

Comment: mc1 and mc2 exist in the same level 2 mc deep from stage. The rotations are known I can relate their rotations to each other or to stage no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this piece of code might help you out:
You can specify a point which you want to translate into the coordinate system of another movie clip.

```
public static function localToLocal(from:Sprite, to:Sprite, origin:Point):Object
{
     var point:Point = new Point(origin.x,origin.y);
     point = from.localToGlobal(point);
     point = to.globalToLocal(point);
     return point;
}
```

The problem remains, if there are multiple sub-movieclips, that are rotated individually. Otherwise you can use just the one rotation you have applied to the movieclip, and apply it to a new wrapper-clip.

Comment: amazing!! thanks for the wonderful function. It solved my problem but of course it doesnt handle the rotation, but handling the rotation is simple. Here is how it worked:mc2.addChild(child);

var p:Point = localToLocal(mc1, mc2, new Point(child.x, child.y));
child.x = p.x;
child.y = p.y;
child.rotation -= mc2.rotation;

function localToLocal(from:Sprite, to:Sprite, origin:Point):Point
{
     var point:Point = new Point(origin.x, origin.y);
     point = from.localToGlobal(point);
     point = to.globalToLocal(point);
     return point;
}

Comment: unfortunately I`m not able to vote up as I dont have enough reputation

Comment: yes, was going to say that. i have kept this code in my snippets for a long time http://rockonflash.wordpress.com/2007/05/16/as3-localtolocal-and-coordinatetools/

Comment: Even if you can't vote up you can still accept the answer so everyone knows it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `localToGlobal()` and `globalToLocal()` to achieve that.

```
var positionInMc1:Point = new Point(child.x, child.y);
var positionInStage:Point = mc1.localToGlobal(positionInMc1);
var positionInMc2:Point = mc2.globalToLocal(positionInStage);

mc2.addChild(child);
mc2.x = positionInMc2.x;
mc2.y = positionInMc2.y;
```

Edit:

However, this will not handle the rotation correctly. So you will probably have to rotate `child` after that to correct for the rotation of `mc1` and `mc2`. As they are in the same level, you should probably rotate `child` by the difference between their respective rotations.

Edit:

From the code you posted below:

```
child.rotation -= mc2.rotation;
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I think this is the same concept as the function posted by twall. It solves it, as for the rotation it is easy to sum/subtract the rotations to keep the correct rotation. All the ass pain was in the position. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you got deeply nested transforms I'd use something like this. For example you have nested sprites `mc1.mc2.mc3` and you want to reattach `mc3` to `mc4`. This one looks how much the right vector (1, 0) in one coordinate system differs from same vector in another one.

```
function reattach(target:DisplayObject, to:DisplayObjectContainer):void {
    var center:Point = target.localToGlobal(new Point(0,0));
    // vector (1, 0) from old local coordinate system
    var oldVector:Point = target.localToGlobal(new Point(1,0)).subtract(center);
    var newCenter:Point = to.globalToLocal(center);
    to.addChild(target);
    target.x = newCenter.x;
    target.y = newCenter.y;
    // vector (1, 0) from new local coordinate system
    var newVector:Point = target.localToGlobal(new Point(1,0)).subtract(center);
    // angle between these two vectors
    var angle:Number = Math.acos((oldVector.x*newVector.x + oldVector.y*newVector.y)/(oldVector.length*newVector.length)) * 180 / Math.PI;
    if (oldVector.x*newVector.y - oldVector.y*newVector.x > 0) angle = -angle;
    // rotating for delta angle
    target.rotation += angle;
}

reattach(mc1.mc2.mc3, mc4);
```

Have to be modified if any of the sprites are scaled